# Is it possible to force a Node VM context to stop running?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node has a [VM module](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html), which makes it possible to run arbitrary JavaScript code in a new context.

What I'd like to do, is find a way to stop this code from executing on a callback function, in a reliable way the context cannot stop.

Here's a tricky sample I've been trying to figure out a solution for.

```
'use strict';

var vm = require('vm');

var src = '(' + (function(kill) {
    try {
        kill();
    }
    catch (ex) {}

    // Can this be prevented?
    while (true) {
        // Nothing.
    }
}) + ')';
var script = new vm.Script(src);
var func = script.runInNewContext();

func(function() {
    console.log('This should somehow stop that VM from running.');
});
```

Because the try/catch statement catches any exception, just throwing an exception is out. Without someway to stop the script from the callback, the code then enters a dummy loop which runs forever (well, until it hits whatever timeout is set, wasting CPU cycles until then).

The `timeout` VM feature isn't quite what I want, because I want to stop the script on-command. I could move this code to running in another process and kill that process, but that adds a lot of overhead.

I'm open to inventive solutions on this one. Perhaps something using [Node's Debug objects](https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/vm/#vmrunindebugcontextcode)?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to execute the code in a child process, where you can just kill off the child process early if you need to. You'd probably want to do this anyway if there is the possibility of infinite loops, to avoid starving the event loop of your main script.

Comment: True, I mentioned that in the question, it's just a bit of overhead. I have no problem having a timeout in general, so rogue code doesn't fully consume it, it's just inefficient to have to rely on it if the kill API is called.